# Opening a pdf/Wordpad file at Installation finish

Tags: nsis

I am using HM NIS Edit 2.03. For my setup installation, I need to open a help file at the end of the installation. The file may be a pdf, notepad or a word page file. I tried `!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN` but it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

`MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN` can only start real applications, to start other things you can use `MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME`. If you are already using `MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME` for something else you can use a custom run function:

```
Function MyFinishRun
ExecShell "" "$instdir\readme.doc"
FunctionEnd

!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION MyFinishRun
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```